# mgp25 - Whatsapi Registration issue for new whatsapp version

Tags: php, registration, whatsapp

I want to send message to whatsapp number from web. I have used mgp25. However, I get registration error due to older version. The version that I have entered is 2.17.121. Attached error screen below:

Registration Issue for older version
[image]

Could you help me with it?

Comment: Guys please answer. Please let me know if you need any more information if you have not understood the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The library seem to be end-of-support (https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/issues/2116)

I've tried to solve it also, and I managed to change the version in WHATSAPP_VER and WHATSAPP_USER_AGENT but this causes a "bad_token" error:

So so far I have the conclusion:

```
generateRequestToken()
```

function under

```
chat-api/src/token.php
```

uses a couple of keys, (one has a comment // 2.16.148) which seem to be invalid also, and need to be updated along with the version.

If I manage to solve this I'll update the answer, but in all cases, whatsapp appears to not to want this to work making "mgp25" unusable.

UPDATE:
You just need the Classes MD5 for a working version: ie when you update the constants file, also update $classesMd5 value for that version:

For example

```
2.16.328
1I2weuZmVg+uL50+HXeSJw==
```

Comment: Thanks. I have seen same problem for other API not only for mgp25. But mgp25 is supposed to be used as per the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Updated $classesMD5 value of #Alex answer:
You just need the Classes MD5 for a working version: ie when you update the constants file, also update $classesMd5 value for that version:

```
Version: 2.17.422
ClassesDex: XBpFzrmxmNufLCYF3Qmm1A==
```

**I am Just posting the updated $classesMD5 value** rest of the credit goes to #alex